# How to make conversion function work?

Tags: c++, parsing, data-conversion

I have a code that I'm trying to learn how to parse in C++.  I understood everything I did, but I don't understand how to work with the likes of atoi(), atof (), strtod ().   I know what it's supposed to do, but I don't understand why the compiler doesn't like it.  My focus on the error is "scores[line_count] =  strtod (score);"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int readScores(string inputFile, string name[], float scores[], int     array_size)
{
//delcare variables
ifstream infile;
int line_count = 0;
string line;
string named;
float score;
char character;
int word_index;
string names[array_size];


// open input file
infile.open(inputFile);

//Check if file opens succesfully.
if(infile.fail())
{
    cout << "File cannot open!!" << endl;
    return -1;
}

while(getline(infile, line))
{
    cout << line << endl;
    // PARSING GOES HERE

    word_index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i < (int)line.length(); i++)
    {
        character = line[i];

        if (character == ',')
        {
            names[line_count] = named;
            named = "";
            word_index++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(word_index == 0)
            {
                named += character;

            }
            else if (word_index == 1)
            {
                score += character;
                cout << character << " " << endl;
            }
        }

    }
scores[line_count] =  strtod (score);



    line_count++;

}

//close file
infile.close();

//return line count
return line_count;
cout << line_count << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
int array_size = 50;
string inputFile = "Test.txt";
string name [array_size];
float scores [array_size];


readScores(inputFile, name, scores, array_size);
}
```

Comment: "The compiler doesn't like it" is not a very helpful description.

Comment: It gives me an error.  It says, "Cannot covert float to const char* for argument 1."

Comment: @Robbie so why isn't it helpful? You are passing `float` instead of `char *`!

Comment: I am reading from a file, which says, "Robbie,59,32,23"  it reads it as a string as a whole.   I am trying to convert 59 to a float value.   

I'm just learning how to parse in this method.  I guess stringstream is the best method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function strtod() takes the form

```
double strtod (const char* str, char** endptr);
```

But you only give it the string.

As you can see it takes two parameters, the string you wish to convert to a double, and an "endptr". The endptr is described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/) as a

> Reference to an already allocated object of type char*, whose value is set by > the function to the next character in str after the numerical value.
>   This parameter can also be a null pointer, in which case it is not used.

So you need to declare a char pointer to save the next character after the decimal, even if there wont be one. This allows you to pull multiple doubles from a single string, much like a tokenizer.

```
char * endPtr;
scores[line_count] = strtod(score, &endPtr);
```

**Edit**

As Alex Lop pointed out, you aren't even passing a string to strtod, you're passing a float. It appears you would like to cast the float to a double?

Comment: Alright...say I change it to atof(score)...I still get the same error.

    double afof(const char* _nptr)

Comment: Thats because atof() converts a string to a float, and you would still be passing it a float. My suggestion would be to look at the manual pages for functions before using them, so you know exactly what they do, and what parameters they need to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the compiler doesn't like it. Please read the description of [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/).

> **double strtod (const char* str, char** endptr);**
>
> Convert `string` to
>   `double`.
>
> Parses the C-string `str` interpreting its content as a floating
>   point number (according to the current locale) and returns its value
>   as a `double`. If endptr is not a `null` pointer, the function also sets
>   the value of `endptr` to point to the first character after the number.
>
> The function first discards as many whitespace characters (as in
>   isspace) as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is
>   found. Then, starting from this character, takes as many characters as
>   possible that are valid following a syntax resembling that of floating
>   point literals (see below), and interprets them as a numerical value.
>   A pointer to the rest of the string after the last valid character is
>   stored in the object pointed by `endptr`.

And in your code you pass to `strtod` only one parameter which is of type `float` and store the returned result of `double` into an array of `float`s. If you want to move the value of `float` from one variable to another, you don't need any "convertion" function:

```
scores[line_count] = score;
```

*NOTE:* I didn't really review your code as you asked specifically about `scores[line_count] =  strtod (score);`. But after I looked how you modify `score`, maybe it should have been `string` and not `float`. If so, then it is the another point to fix.